# Подключение к БД Qt

Tags: c++, sql, qt, sql-server

Всем привет. Можно ли как-то получить список доступных для подключения БД, а не явно задавать имя БД в методе setDatabaseName() ? Грубо говоря, чтобы вывести все доступные к подключению в combo box и уже из них выбирать, к какой подключаться?

Comment: Это зависит от того, какую СУБД вы используете.

Comment: Использую ms sql server

Comment: https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qsqldatabase.html#connectionNames , или имеется ввиду что-то другое?

Comment: Для начала надо определиться, что именно обозначает "доступная для подключения БД".

Comment: Допустим, на сервере работают одновременно 3 БД. Нужно обнаружить их все и занести в список, чтобы в интерфейсе уже выбирать, к какой из них подключиться, а не прописывать руками в коде все параметры подключения

Comment: Не путайте СУБД (систему управления базой данных или _сервер_) и собственно БД (базу данных). К первой можно _подключиться_, вторую можно _открыть_. Одна СУБД может управлять несколькими БД. | Подключаетесь к sql-server, а потом выполняете запрос, показанный msi - получите список баз. Далее можете открыть любую из них (если есть права: см. второй ответ).

Answer (score 1):

Для этого надо поработать с API какой-нибудь СУБД  и это будет ваше частное решение.

А если вы говорите об общем функционале, то, собственно, никак и Qt тут не исключение.

Тут принцип простой и связан с безопасностью баз данных. Доступ к СУБД  имеет ее администатор, а доступ к конкретной базе данных имеет администратор этой базы данных (в общем случае это разные люди).

Например, таким образом организованы СУБД на хостинговых серверах. Иначе, любой новый сайт мог был получить доступ к списку всех БД, управляемых данной СУБД, что, как вы можете догадаться, нежелательно.

Comment: Понял, спасибо. Пока что обычного подключения хватит тогда

Answer (score 0):

Это имеете в виду?

```
select name from sys.databases;
```